# Powershell script for replacing name

Tags: powershell

I have an array which contains list of text which needs names to be replaced.
For example: Monday, Tuesday,Wednesday are text in my array being called from test.txt file
I want to rename each of them to Monday1111,Tuesday1111,Wednesday1111.
Below is my powershell script

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb "https://test.com"
$DocLib = $Web.Lists["Documents"]          
$filename = @(Get-Content F:\ish\test.txt)
foreach($ListItem in $DocLib.Items)
   {
     if($ListItem["Name"] -match $filename[i]) 
       {
         $ListItem.File.CheckOut()
         $ListItem["Name"] = $filename+ "1111"  
                   
         $ListItem.Update()
         $ListItem.File.CheckIn($ListItem["Name"] + ".pdf")
   }
```

}

Comment: Are the `$ListItem["Name"]` properties an exact whole-word match or are names like `BlueMonday` also a match?

Comment: It is not an exact match... It is something like bluemonday

Comment: You mean the textfile has 'bluemonday' or the listitem["Name]" has that? Please show some examples

Answer (score 1):

Your code is comparing the $ListItem to `$filename[i]`. There is no index `i` defined in your loop (and also, if there was, it should be `$i`).

If the names in the list should be matched as whole-word to the names in your text file, this should do it:

```
$Web       = Get-SPWeb "https://test.com"
$DocLib    = $Web.Lists["Documents"]          
$filenames = Get-Content 'F:\ish\test.txt'

foreach ($ListItem in ($DocLib.Items | Where-Object { $filenames -contains $_["Name"] })) {
    $ListItem["Name"] += "1111"
    $ListItem.File.CheckOut()
              
    $ListItem.Update()
    $ListItem.File.CheckIn($ListItem["Name"] + ".pdf")
}
```

---

Thanks for giving more detail.
If the filenames in the text file are **partial** matches to the names of the listitems, you'll need to find the listitems that match a certain file name first.
Then rename this listitem with the name from the textfile with "1111" appended to it.

Try:

```
$Web       = Get-SPWeb "https://test.com"
$DocLib    = $Web.Lists["Documents"]          
$filenames = Get-Content 'F:\ish\test.txt' | Select-Object -Unique

# loop through each item of the text file
foreach($name in $filenames) {
    # try and find a listitem name that has the $name in it
    foreach ($ListItem in ($DocLib.Items | Where-Object { $_["Name"] -like "*$name*" })) {
        $ListItem.File.CheckOut()
        $ListItem["Name"] = $name + "1111"
        $ListItem.Update()
        $ListItem.File.CheckIn($ListItem["Name"] + ".pdf")
    }
}
```

---

As per your comment, you would like an output file where the results are shown, here's updated code that outputs a CSV file you can open with Excel.

```
$Web        = Get-SPWeb "https://test.com"
$DocLib     = $Web.Lists["Documents"]          
$filenames  = Get-Content 'F:\ish\test.txt' | Select-Object -Unique
$outputFile = 'F:\ish\RenameResults.csv'

# loop through each item of the text file
$result = foreach($name in $filenames) {
    # try and find a listitem name that has the $name in it
    $renamed = foreach ($ListItem in ($DocLib.Items | Where-Object { $_["Name"] -like "*$name*" })) {
        $oldName = $ListItem["Name"]
        $newName = $name + "1111"
        $ListItem.File.CheckOut()
        $ListItem["Name"] = $newName
        $ListItem.Update()
        $ListItem.File.CheckIn($ListItem["Name"] + ".pdf")
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            SearchName      = $name
            OldListItemName = $oldName
            NewListItemName = $newName
        }
    }
    # output the resulting updates or an object showing which search name
    # did not match any of the ListItem names
    if (!$renamed) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            SearchName      = $name
            OldListItemName = 'Not found'
            NewListItemName = ''
        }        
    }
    else { $renamed }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This script isn't helping me. Where do I include the index i for each of the element to be replaced?

Comment: @ish_dev That is why I asked about the whole-word or partial match.. Please add a few examples to your question so we know what exactly you need to match and what the new name for the item should be. Now I'm just guessing.

Comment: Lets say the array $filename contains the values Monday,Tuesday.
And my SharePoint document library contains Monday1234.pdf,Tuesday5678.pdf

Now I want my script to pickup Monday from the array, and rename it to Monday1111.pdf.
Next pickup Tuesday from array and rename to Tuesday1111.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much. This workshop fine but it seems to skip updating few values from the test.txt . Unable to figure out why  . Is there a way I can save these output in a text file so I can use it for comparison later?

Comment: @ish_dev I have added new code to capture and output the results to a CSV file